# Boundary characters not working in c#

Tags: c#

i have following issues in c# code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         string line="have a nice day with nice(songs)";
         string pattern=@"\bnice\b";
       string replaced_line=Regex.Replace(line, pattern, "Good", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
}
}
```

output-: have a Good day with nice(songs)

The above output is fine. but the below code is not replacing

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         string line="have a nice day with nice(songs)";
         string to_replace="nice";
       string replaced_line=Regex.Replace(line, @"\b"+to_replace+"\b", "Good", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
}
}
```

output-: have a nice day with nice(songs)

it is not replacing

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Typographical error: missing `@` - `"\b"` is not the same as `@"\b"`.

Comment: Can u please repeat the code with changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
 string replaced_line=Regex.Replace(line, @"\b"+to_replace+"\b", "Good", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

You escape it only 1 time but you must do it every string. So should be

```
 string replaced_line=Regex.Replace(line, @"\b"+to_replace+@"\b", "Good", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

(add @)

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

`string to_replace= @"\bnice\b";` is right and it is not equal to  `string to_replace= @"\b"+to_replace+@"\b"`